# Tableau - How to aggregate and count the occurrence of TRUE and FALSE?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a simple Excel file and I would like to use Tableau to count the occurrence of TRUE and FALSE. But instead of showing the numbers, the Tableau table shows 'Abc'...

Below is the screenshot, upper-left corner shows how my Excel file looks like, the Tableau table is also shown. How can I let Tableau display the numbers, say, for `zip 10086` there are 2 `TRUE`.

[image]

Comment: Drag the Number of Records measure onto the label shelf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a couple of ways:

1. Drag 'Number of Records' to the Text Mark
2. Drag 'Passed' to the Text Mark, right click it and select Measure -> Count